# How to make the dot '.' and the underscore '_' behave like the space in $text index in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, indexing, nosql

I'm about to add a search functionality in my application which has a users collection in the Mongo data base. each user has a unique username with the rules:

- all letters are English lowercase letters.
- can also contain numbers, dots and underscores.

Each user also has a name - a string of letters and spaces, similar to Instagram and Twitter rules. So I want to make a search functionality that searches in the users collection by the name and userName properties. I tried to create an index for these properties like this:

> db.users.createIndex({"userName": "text", "name": "text"})

This is not a good solution at all, because for example if there is a user with the userName of "hasan.yousef", and I searched for "yousef", this user will not show up.
I would like to hear from you guys of a better solution or a better index design. I'm also not exactly sure of the size of the problem, and I want to read more about similar problems in other resources.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Atlas Search, you can configure this behavior via a mapping analyzer. See https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/analyzers/custom/.

For text indexes, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#tokenization-delimiters implies the tokenization is not configurable. You can create a second field in your document that stores the text transformed for search (i.e. _ and . replaced with spaces) and use that field for the text index.